# Is there a tool for the following merging in R?

Tags: r, merge

I am working with intervals as such:

```
chr1:004336501-004336560   0.3437   
chr1:004340069-004340128   0.3437   
chr1:004350335-004350394   0.3437   
chr1:004354213-004354272   0.3218   
chr1:004380332-004380391   0.3218   
chr1:004481060-004481119   0.3218   
chr1:004488728-004488787   0.3607   
...
```

I would like to get the following:

```
chr1  004336501  004350394  0.3437
chr1  004354213  004481119  0.3218
...
```

I would be surprised if there is no R function to do this. I don't want to use loops in R because the file is huge. I would appreciate any suggestion that I could develop.

Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't your example output have three lines?

Comment: I think you should explain more how the output is to be created. None of the ranges in your example overlap with each other, and if the only criteria for merging is that they have the same value in column 4, I'm not sure if there's any reason that a given value couldn't repeat elsewhere for a distinct region or even on a different chromosome (I'm assuming this is genome coordinates, but you haven't said). I can't think of many applications in genomics where the merge based only on your criteria is useful, unless your application is very specific,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this with without a loop, unless your matrix subsetting skills are crazy good.

Here's how I might do it, if your original data is `df`

```
> s <- split(strsplit(df$V1, "[:-]"), df$V2)
> cb <- cbind(Reduce(rbind, lapply(s, function(x) {
          x <- do.call(rbind, x)
          c(x[1,1], x[1,2], x[nrow(x),3])
      })), names(s))
> data.frame(unname(cb))
#     X1        X2        X3     X4
# 1 chr1 004354213 004481119 0.3218
# 2 chr1 004336501 004350394 0.3437
# 3 chr1 004488728 004488787 0.3607
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Studying your function helps me understand R's functions better.

Answer (score 5):

you could also try:

```
 library(data.table)
 library(devtools)
 source_gist(11380733)

 #Updated based on @Ananda Mahto's comments
 DT <- cSplit(df, "V1", "[:-]", fixed = FALSE)[,
          list(chr = V1_1[1], First = V1_2[1], Last = V1_3[.N]), by = V2]
 setkey(DT,V2)

 DT
 #      V2  chr     First     Last
 #1: 0.3218 chr1 004354213 004481119
 #2: 0.3437 chr1 004336501 004350394
 #3: 0.3607 chr1 004488728 004488787
```

Or  use `regex` to change the multiple delimiters to a single one.

```
 DT1 <- cSplit(transform(df, V1=gsub(":", "-", V1)),
            "V1", "-")[,list(Chr=V1_1[1], ColN1=V1_2[1], ColN2=V1_3[.N]), by=V2]
 setkey(DT1, V2)
  DT1
  #      V2  Chr     ColN1     ColN2
  #1: 0.3218 chr1 004354213 004481119
  #2: 0.3437 chr1 004336501 004350394
  #3: 0.3607 chr1 004488728 004488787
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(V1 = c("chr1:004336501-004336560", "chr1:004340069-004340128", 
 "chr1:004350335-004350394", "chr1:004354213-004354272", "chr1:004380332-004380391", 
 "chr1:004481060-004481119", "chr1:004488728-004488787"), V2 = c(0.3437, 
 0.3437, 0.3437, 0.3218, 0.3218, 0.3218, 0.3607)), .Names = c("V1", 
 "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Pretty much exactly how I would do it :-) +1

Comment: @Ananda Mahto Thanks. Any options in `cSplit` or `concat.split.multiple` to take multiple delimiters for a single column.

Comment: the version of `cSplit` currently at the Gist has a `fixed` argument, so you can set that to `FALSE` and use `":|-"` or `"[:-]"` as your `sep`. So, your answer could be: `cSplit(df, "V1", "[:-]", fixed = FALSE)[, list(chr = V1_1[1], First = V1_2[1], Last = V1_3[.N]), by = V2]`.

Comment: @Ananda Mahto Thanks for the reply.  It certainly helps.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an idea based on dplyr and tidyr

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
> dat
                       V1     V2
    1 004336501-004336560 0.3437
    2 004340069-004340128 0.3437
    3 004350335-004350394 0.3437
    4 004354213-004354272 0.3218
    5 004380332-004380391 0.3218
    6 004481060-004481119 0.3218
    7 004488728-004488787 0.3607

dat %>% separate(V1, c("V1a", "V1b")) %>% group_by(V2) %>% summarise(V1a=min(V1a), V1b=max(V1b)) %>% unite(V1, V1a, V1b, sep="-")

      V2                  V1
1 0.3218 004354213-004481119
2 0.3437 004336501-004350394
3 0.3607 004488728-004488787
```

Comment: The initial data is slightly different than the one you showed.  Perhaps, using the initial data `dat %>% separate(V1, c("V1a", "V1b", "V1c"), "[:-]") %>% group_by(V2) %>% summarise(V1a=V1a[1], V1b=V1b[1], V1c=V1c[n()])`

Answer (score 1):

My updated answer after realizing nrussel's point.  I believe the following should now work appropriately, albeit a little messy function involved.

```
> dat
                        V1     V2
1 chr1:004336501-004336560 0.3437
2 chr1:004340069-004340128 0.3437
3 chr1:004350335-004350394 0.3437
4 chr1:004354213-004354272 0.3218
5 chr1:004380332-004380391 0.3218
6 chr1:004481060-004481119 0.3218
7 chr1:004488728-004488787 0.3607

require(stringr)
# Split data based upon V2
dat_split <- split(dat, f = as.factor(dat[,2]))

# function to find matches (which appear to be the lowest and highest values)
find_matches <- function(dat_split){
  x <- str_split_fixed(dat_split[,1], "[//:|//-]", 3)
  out <- c(x[1,1], min(x[,2]), max(x[,3]), unique(dat_split[,2]))
  return(out)
}

out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(dat_split, FUN = function(x) find_matches(x)))
rownames(out) <- NULL

> out
     [,1]   [,2]        [,3]        [,4]    
[1,] "chr1" "004354213" "004481119" "0.3218"
[2,] "chr1" "004336501" "004350394" "0.3437"
[3,] "chr1" "004488728" "004488787" "0.3607"
```

Comment: Note that the OP is also looking to merge the ranges of LHS and RHS  of the hyphens based on the decimal value in the far right column.

Comment: @nrussell, thank you for pointing out that oversight of mine.  I have edited my answer to accomplish what I now understand is the current question.